# GtkScrolledWindow: how to keep scroll-bar location when switching pages in GtkNotebook?

Tags: gtk3

I have an application using GtkNotebook with pages of GtkScrolledWindow. I added many pages to GtkNotebook. One type of page is a GtkDrawingArea - it needs a scrollbar to move the graphics around. When I moved the horizontal and vertical scrollbar to the right and bottom respectively, then I switch to another page and switch back, its horizontal and vertical scrollbar all go back to left and top respectively.

How do I keep the scrollbar positions of the GtkDrawingArea ScrolledWindow parent to their position before the switching?

I read gtk3 document on GtkNotebook, GtkScrolledWindow and GtkAdjustment, no mention of such property or signal handling.

Comment: How is the hierarchy of the widgets? Did you add a GtkViewport between the ScrolledWindow and the DrawingArea?

Comment: That magically fixed my problem. But from document on line for GtkViewport, it says: If a widget has native scrolling abilities, such as GtkTextView, GtkTreeView or GtkIconView, it can be added to a GtkScrolledWindow with gtk_container_add(). If a widget does not, you must first add the widget to a GtkViewport, then add the viewport to the scrolled window. gtk_container_add() does this automatically if a child that does not implement GtkScrollable is added to a GtkScrolledWindow, so you can ignore the presence of the viewport.

Comment: Sorry for the long comments, my question is how come gtk_container_add() does not insert the viewport here? If it does, it should work properly. But that's not what I see.

Comment: it does say that in the documentation but there's no code in your question. Also not sure if there's a bug on Gtk+. From my experience i always add a view port programmatically or via glade. Glade won't even allow you to add such widgets without adding a viewport.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.